GitHub Actions: Permission denied when trying to create workflow file via GitHub App
I'm implementing a GitHub Actions workflow designed to generate and commit a new workflow file for each pull request. However, when the workflow attempts to create the file .github/workflows/qr-workflow-{PR_NUMBER}.yml, it fails with the following error:
[remote rejected] main -> main (refusing to allow a GitHub App to create or update workflow .github/workflows/qr-workflow-1.yml without workflows permission)
This occurs despite the workflow running with what I believed were sufficient GitHub App permissions. I'm confused as to why the 'workflows' permission isn't being recognized or how to correctly grant this permission to allow the creation of new workflow files.
I created a GitHub Actions workflow that uses actions/checkout and Git commands to dynamically generate and commit a new workflow file. The workflow was triggered on pull request creation and was supposed to:

Generate a new YAML file with a name like qr-workflow-{PR_NUMBER}.yml
Commit this file to the .github/workflows/ directory
Push the changes to the repository

Here's the relevant part of my workflow:
name: Create QR Code Workflow for PR

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]

jobs:
  create-qr-workflow:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    permissions:
      contents: write

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Configure Git
        run: |
          git config user.name "github-actions[bot]"
          git config user.email "41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
      
      - name: Copy and rename file to .github/workflows directory
        run: |
          PR_NUMBER=$(jq --raw-output .pull_request.number "$GITHUB_EVENT_PATH")
          cp qr-workflow-template.txt ".github/workflows/qr-workflow-$PR_NUMBER.yml"
      
      - name: Commit and push the new workflow file
        run: |
          git fetch origin main
          git checkout main
          git pull origin main
          git add .github/workflows/
          git commit -m "Add qr-workflow-$PR_NUMBER.yml for PR #$PR_NUMBER"
          git push origin main
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT_TOKEN }}

      - name: Trigger the new workflow
        run: |
          PR_NUMBER=$(jq --raw-output .pull_request.number "$GITHUB_EVENT_PATH")
          WORKFLOW_FILE="qr-workflow-$PR_NUMBER.yml"
          gh workflow run $WORKFLOW_FILE
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT_TOKEN }}


There is an actions permissions, but even setting that to write isn't sufficient. You need to use a personal access token to modify a workflow file from Actions, with fine-grained scopes contents:write and workflows:write. See this discussion (my answer there)
